# How to use subroutines in perl modules, which are present in perl scripts

Tags: perl, perl-module

I need help in accessing the subroutines present in the perl scripts in perl modules.

**getHosts()** and **getIP()** subroutines are present in /tmp/utils/Utili.pl (perl script).

when I compile that master.pl,  I am getting **Undefined subroutine &Modules::test2::getIP called at /tmp/Modules/test2.pm**

**getIP()** subroutine was present in the **/tmp/utils/Utili.pl** perl script.

I cannot take risk of changing **/tmp/utils/Utili.pl** to perl module, since it was used in hundreds of scripts and requires lot of testing effort.

could some one help me on this.?

Also, its not only this subroutine, whatever subroutines which were present in the /tmp/utils/Utili.pl perl script if i call in test2.pm iam getting the same error. the same subroutines are working if i call in test1.pm in both the modules, iam using the below lines to access the subroutines.

```
require "/tmp/utils/Log.pl";
require "/tmp/utils/Utili.pl";
```

please find the sudo code below.

Example:

**master script: master.pl**

in master.pl iam calling new subroutine in perl modules "test1.pm" and "test2.pm" as below.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use lib "/tmp";

use Modules::test1;
use Modules::test2;

my $installation1 = Modules::test1->new();

my $installation2 = Modules::test2->new();
```

[download]
test1.pm:

in "test1.pm" i have the below code,

```
package Modules::test1;

use strict;
use warnings;

require "/tmp/utils/Log.pl";
require "/tmp/utils/Utili.pl";

my @Hosts=getHosts();

sub new()

{

print "inside new\n";

}
```

[download]
test2.pm

in "test2.pm" i have the below code,

```
package Modules::test2;

use strict;
use warnings;

my @IP=getIP();

require "/tmp/utils/Log.pl";
require "/tmp/utils/Utili.pl";

sub new()
{

print "inside new\n";

}
```

Comment: Try `my @Hosts=main::getHosts();` instead of `my @Hosts=getHosts();`. Btw. it's not the very best practice to abuse *.pl as *.pm. Better would be to move `getHosts()` to a separate module and let all others `use` that.

Comment: my @Hosts=main::getHosts();   still i get same error..   Undefined subroutine &main::getHosts

Comment: if i use the same subroutine in test1.pm it was working fine.

Comment: Also if i comment out  the  calling of "test1" perl module in the master perl  script (use Modules::test1;)   then it works for test2.pm

Comment: only for the first perl module, it was working.. I was able to call and any subroutines present in the "/tmp/utils/Utili.pl"

Comment: iam using  below lines in every perl modules to acces the subroutines.                                    require "/tmp/utils/Log.pl";
require "/tmp/utils/Utili.pl";

Comment: `require` happens at runtime, so in test2, when you call `getIP()`, it has not yet loaded that sub from the Utili.pl file. Try moving the `require` statements above the call to the sub.

Comment: example: `perl -E 'say 5; say require Data::Dumper;'`

Comment: sorry, i have corrected that but forgot to update here.. still iam not able to acces the subtoutines in test2.pm

Answer (score 1):

`require` happens at runtime, so in this code:

```
my @IP=getIP();

require "/tmp/utils/Log.pl";
require "/tmp/utils/Utili.pl";
```

`getIP()` has not yet been loaded from the `Utili.pl` file, so it's looking in it's own scope for that sub. Move things around so that the subs get loaded before you call them:

```
require "/tmp/utils/Log.pl";
require "/tmp/utils/Utili.pl";

my @IP=getIP();
```

Comment: sorry, i have corrected that but forgot to update here.. still iam not able to acces the subroutines in test2.pm

Comment: Also if i comment out the calling of "test1" perl module in the master perl script (use Modules::test1;) then it works for test2.pm

Comment: any suggestions on this please.. ??